# Sending an e-mail from android app using Exchange activesync

Tags: java, android, email, smtp, exchange-server

I am trying to send an e-mail from within an android application. I have made a functioning demo using gmail smtp servers, but migrating to using a Microsoft Exchange 2013 mail server is proving dificult. I get the following exception trace (I have anonymized the server name and IP-address):

```
10-21 10:21:00.162 14167-14546/no.uib.jmi053.tefapplication W/System.err: javax.mail.MessagingException: Exception reading response;
10-21 10:21:00.162 14167-14546/no.uib.jmi053.tefapplication W/System.err:   nested exception is:
10-21 10:21:00.162 14167-14546/no.uib.jmi053.tefapplication W/System.err:   javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Read error: ssl=0xb895bf18: I/O error during system call, Connection reset by peer
10-21 10:21:00.172 14167-14546/no.uib.jmi053.tefapplication W/System.err:     at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.readServerResponse(SMTPTransport.java:1611)
10-21 10:21:00.172 14167-14546/no.uib.jmi053.tefapplication W/System.err:     at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1369)
10-21 10:21:00.172 14167-14546/no.uib.jmi053.tefapplication W/System.err:     at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:412)
10-21 10:21:00.172 14167-14546/no.uib.jmi053.tefapplication W/System.err:     at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:288)
10-21 10:21:00.172 14167-14546/no.uib.jmi053.tefapplication W/System.err:     at no.uib.jmi053.tefapplication.io.mail.GmailSender.send(GmailSender.java:109)
10-21 10:21:00.172 14167-14546/no.uib.jmi053.tefapplication W/System.err:     at no.uib.jmi053.tefapplication.io.mail.AsyncSendTask.doInBackground(AsyncSendTask.java:70)
10-21 10:21:00.172 14167-14546/no.uib.jmi053.tefapplication W/System.err:     at no.uib.jmi053.tefapplication.io.mail.AsyncSendTask.doInBackground(AsyncSendTask.java:12)
10-21 10:21:00.172 14167-14546/no.uib.jmi053.tefapplication W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
10-21 10:21:00.172 14167-14546/no.uib.jmi053.tefapplication W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
10-21 10:21:00.172 14167-14546/no.uib.jmi053.tefapplication W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
10-21 10:21:00.172 14167-14546/no.uib.jmi053.tefapplication W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
10-21 10:21:00.172 14167-14546/no.uib.jmi053.tefapplication W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
10-21 10:21:00.172 14167-14546/no.uib.jmi053.tefapplication W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
10-21 10:21:00.172 14167-14546/no.uib.jmi053.tefapplication W/System.err: Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Read error: ssl=0xb895bf18: I/O error during system call, Connection reset by peer
10-21 10:21:00.172 14167-14546/no.uib.jmi053.tefapplication W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_read(Native Method)
10-21 10:21:00.172 14167-14546/no.uib.jmi053.tefapplication W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl$SSLInputStream.read(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:728)
10-21 10:21:00.172 14167-14546/no.uib.jmi053.tefapplication W/System.err:     at com.sun.mail.util.TraceInputStream.read(TraceInputStream.java:110)
10-21 10:21:00.172 14167-14546/no.uib.jmi053.tefapplication W/System.err:     at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:162)
10-21 10:21:00.172 14167-14546/no.uib.jmi053.tefapplication W/System.err:     at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fillbuf(BufferedInputStream.java:149)
10-21 10:21:00.172 14167-14546/no.uib.jmi053.tefapplication W/System.err:     at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:234)
10-21 10:21:00.172 14167-14546/no.uib.jmi053.tefapplication W/System.err:     at com.sun.mail.util.LineInputStream.readLine(LineInputStream.java:88)
10-21 10:21:00.172 14167-14546/no.uib.jmi053.tefapplication W/System.err:     at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.readServerResponse(SMTPTransport.java:1589)
10-21 10:21:00.172 14167-14546/no.uib.jmi053.tefapplication W/System.err:   ... 12 more
```

After consulting with the client, it seems the problem is that I am trying to connect to their server in a non-standard way, or in a way that the server does not recognize. I am not that familiar with Microsoft Exchange, and I am not quite sure how to connect to the server in a way that it can work with.

This is my sender class:

```
package no.uib.jmi053.tefapplication.io.mail;

import com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.activation.CommandMap;
import javax.activation.DataHandler;
import javax.activation.DataSource;
import javax.activation.FileDataSource;
import javax.activation.MailcapCommandMap;
import javax.mail.BodyPart;
import javax.mail.Multipart;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart;

/**
 * Created by JoaT Development on 02.10.2015.
 *
 * Handles sending an email from Gmail-client.
 */
public class GmailSender{

    private String _user;
    private String _pass;

    private String[] _to;
    private String _from;

    private String _port;
    private String _sport;

    private String _host;

    private String _subject;
    private String _body;

    private boolean _auth;

    private boolean _debuggable;

    private Multipart _multipart;


    public GmailSender() {
            _host = "mail.company-name.com"; // default smtp server
            _port = "443"; // default smtp port
            _sport = "443"; // default socketfactory port

            _user = ""; // username
            _pass = ""; // password
            _from = ""; // email sent from
            _subject = ""; // email subject
            _body = ""; // email body

            _debuggable = false; // debug mode on or off - default off
            _auth = true; // smtp authentication - default on

            _multipart = new MimeMultipart();

        // There is something wrong with MailCap, javamail can not find a handler for the multipart/mixed part, so this bit needs to be added.
        MailcapCommandMap mc = (MailcapCommandMap) CommandMap.getDefaultCommandMap();
        mc.addMailcap("text/html;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_html");
        mc.addMailcap("text/xml;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_xml");
        mc.addMailcap("text/plain;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.text_plain");
        mc.addMailcap("multipart/*;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.multipart_mixed");
        mc.addMailcap("message/rfc822;; x-java-content-handler=com.sun.mail.handlers.message_rfc822");
        CommandMap.setDefaultCommandMap(mc);
    }

    public GmailSender(String user, String pass) {
        this();
        _user = user;
        _pass = pass;
    }

    public boolean send() throws Exception {
        Properties props = _setProperties();

        if(!_user.equals("") && !_pass.equals("") && _to.length > 0 && !_from.equals("") && !_subject.equals("") && !_body.equals("")) {
            Session session = Session.getInstance(props, null);

            MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);

            msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(_from));

            InternetAddress[] addressTo = new InternetAddress[_to.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < _to.length; i++) {
                addressTo[i] = new InternetAddress(_to[i]);
            }
            msg.setRecipients(MimeMessage.RecipientType.TO, addressTo);

            msg.setSubject(_subject);
            msg.setSentDate(new Date());

            // setup message body
            BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            messageBodyPart.setText(_body);
            _multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

            // Put parts in message
            msg.setContent(_multipart);

            // send email
            SMTPTransport t = (SMTPTransport)session.getTransport("smtps");
            t.connect(_host, _user, _pass);
            t.send(msg);
            t.close();

            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void addAttachment(String filePath, String filename) throws Exception {
        BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filePath);
        messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
        messageBodyPart.setFileName(filename);

        _multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
    }

    private Properties _setProperties() {
        Properties props = new Properties();

        props.put("mail.smtp.host", _host);

        if(_debuggable) {
            props.put("mail.debug", "true");
        }

        if(_auth) {
            props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        }

        props.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
        props.setProperty("mail.host", _host);
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", _port);
        props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.trust", _host);
        props.setProperty("mail.smtp.quitwait", "false");

        return props;
    }

    // the getters and setter
    public void setBody(String _body) {
        this._body = _body;
    }

    public void setTo(String[] toArr) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        this._to=toArr;
    }

    public void setFrom(String string) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        this._from=string;
    }

    public void setSubject(String string) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        this._subject=string;
    }

}
```

And this is from the AsyncTask where it is called from:

```
    sender.setSubject("Reimbursement for " + userName + " " + startDate);
    sender.setBody("This mail has been sent from a Travel Expense Form Application. " +
            "It contains a single expense for " + userName + " " + startDate);
    sender.addAttachment(formPath, userName + " " + startDate + ".xls");
} else {
    sender.setSubject("Travel expense form for " + userName + ": " + startDate + " - "
            + endDateString);
    sender.setBody("This mail has been sent from a Travel Expense Form Application. " +
            "It contains a travel for " + userName + " with route " + travelRoute +
            ": " + startDate + " - " + endDateString);
    sender.addAttachment(formPath, userName + ": " + startDate + " - " + endDateString +
            ".xls");
}
for (int i = 0; i < imagePathList.size(); i++) {
    sender.addAttachment(imagePathList.get(i), findNameFromPath(imagePathList.get(i)));
}
sender.setFrom(sendAddress);
String[] recipients = {toAddress, sendAddress};
sender.setTo(recipients);
success = sender.send();
```

I have earlier tried using javax.mail.Authenticator and authenticating while sending, but to no avail.

I appreciate any input on this as I have been thoroughly stuck on this problem for quite some time now.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I am posting in "Answer".  Not enough points to comment on your question.

Exchange 2013 by default doesn't have a listener for SMTPS on 465 last time I installed it, it had to be built prior. What does this result as for your Microsoft Exchange connection?

```
openssl s_client -starttls smtp -connect example.com:465
```

Just validating you can get proper responses using SMTPS first.

Comment: I am not connecting through 465, but rather 443 which is the default port for Exchange ActiveSync. As for your command suggestion: "openssl is not recognized as an internal or external command", but I might be doing something wrong

Answer (score 0):

I had an similar problem and it's probably a network problem or an firewall problem.

From the log I can see that the ip is :00.000.00.000 so probably you're not connected.

You can try using an helping library like [BackgroundMailLibrary](https://github.com/kristijandraca/BackgroundMailLibrary)

But it's look like network and not code.

Other thing to notice is that you have allowed in you're account access to other mail clients

Comment: Thanks for the input. As I stated, the IP address is anonymized in the post, I do get response from the server.